# How to specify a parameter value for the queue name for sending a msg to service bus

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have the following "hard coded value" code in my Logic App for sending a message to Service Bus

```
                  "actions": {
                    "Send_Message_To_Service_Bus": {
                      "type": "ApiConnection",
                      "inputs": {
                        "host": {
                          "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['servicebus_1']['connectionId']"
                          }
                        },
                        "method": "post",
                        "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('MyQueueOneHardCodedName')}/messages",
                        "body": {
                          "ContentData": "@{base64(item())}",
                          "SessionId": "@items('For_Each_Item_Loop')?['MetaData']?['MetaDataUuid']"
                        },
                        "queries": {
                          "systemProperties": "None"
                        }
                      },
                      "runAfter": {}
                    }
                  },
```

The operative value is

MyQueueOneHardCodedName

I want to replace that with a variable

I have the the parameter setup for correctly, partial code shown below for ServiceBusQueueNameLogicAppParameter

```
      "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
          "defaultValue": {},
          "type": "Object"
        },
        "ServiceBusQueueNameLogicAppParameter": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
```

I have tried

```
"path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('@{parameters('ServiceBusQueueNameLogicAppParameter')}')}/messages",
```

and

```
 "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(@{parameters('ServiceBusQueueNameLogicAppParameter')})}/messages",
```

and

```
 "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('@parameters('ServiceBusQueueNameLogicAppParameter')')}/messages",
```

and

```
"path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(@parameters('ServiceBusQueueNameLogicAppParameter'))}/messages",
```

Most of the errors reflect this:

> is not valid: the string character '@' at position '19' is not
>   expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(parameters('ServiceBusQueueNameLogicAppParameter'))}/messages"
```

**Nested** workflow expressions don't require an additional @ symbol.

HTH

Comment: Ay Caramba.  Is this @ @{ and no @ symbol voodoo documented anywhere?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#expressions

Comment: Thanks for the link